# Not able to add id for ComposeView in xml file

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying add compose in my project.

I am following steps from this : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/adding

The issue I am facing is that, I am not able to add id for the Compose View in the xml file. Have anyone faced this issue. I don't want to completely change the layout to compose I am planning to only update a recyclerview.

```
        <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
            android:id="@+id/aa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Android studio where sometimes new ids in an xml layout file are wrongfully unresolved. Try closing and reopening android studio again and everything will work as expected

Comment: This solves a multitude of problems